# modify mysql DB on user inputting a date and a time

Tags: php, mysql

im working on a quiz web application in php and mysql, i have a user table and quizes table, the admin has access to a table with the quizes name and a checkbox besides every quiz...

lets say theres 10 quizes numbered from 1 to 10, each one of this corresponds to a quiz in mysql,

when you click on the checkbox besides a quiz and hit SEND, that particular quiz is available to a certain user (that on a previous page i already chose) but on that same page i want to put input fields with a time and a date, and that quiz will only be available from the present time to the input date and time....

the user table has a column for every quiz named is_available with default to zero, i want that value change to 1 when that user and quiz are chosen and change back to zero when the date has passed..

i have been thinking how to do this but i have no clue, any ideas or guidelines of where to go or how to start doing this??? i need heeeelp! hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `MySQL`, `PHP`, and [`CRON`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

First, create a relational table -

```
CREATE TABLE `test_expiry` (
    `userid` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,  // user that is taking the test
    `testid` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,  // test number
    `expires` datetime NOT NULL);  // date/time test will expire
       //change names/types as needed / to match your db structure
```

Second, when setting `is_available` = 1, add that test to the `test_expiry` table

```
INSERT INTO `test_expiry` (`userid`,`testid`,`expires`) VALUES (:userid,:testid,:expires)
```

Third, create a php page that will update `is_available` = 0, if date/time has past.

```
SELECT `userid`, `testid` FROM `test_expiry` WHERE `expires` < NOW()
foreach row above ...
UPDATE `tests` SET `is_available` = 0 WHERE `userid` = :userid AND `testid` = :testid
```

And last, set up a cron job-

```
* * * * *  [/path/to/php/]php /path/to/your/script/update.php
```

Comment: thanks, let me check all this info and start learning about CRON cause i've never used it, any guides on using CRON that you'd recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd start off with a form with all your fields, and an action pointing to another PHP script that communicates with your database.  The other PHP script would then read the form data (via $_POST or $_GET) and communicate with the database.  It would then output markup based on this, which forms the output page.

That's the general skeleton.  If you want specific details, I recommend you try to implement as much as you can, even if it's a framework and then post that, and that will give others more to work with.

Comment: actually i already have everuyhing, the forms the tables, all working, my only question is how to implement the think with the time input and that mysql db updates the quizes column on the user selected automatically depending on the date that was inputted

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, then you just need date/time functions.  Both MySQL and PHP have them, depending on which direction you want to go in.  Here's the MySQL ones: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html